# BSD browser information

Tags: freebsd, openbsd, browser, netbsd

I am developing an application and I need some BSD browser information.

Specifically the output of http://browserspy.dk/browser.php

If someone could post the output of Firefox on  FreeBSD.

OpenBSD and Dragonfly or NetBSD would be useful too if anybody has them installed but I mainly need the FreeBSD information.

Comment: Most likely the user agent is `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; FreeBSD amd64; en-US; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0` considering [FF25](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/ports.cgi?query=firefox&stype=name&sektion=all) and the info [here](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Firefox/) crossed with [this](http://user-agent-string.info/list-of-ua/os-detail?os=FreeBSD)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I specifically need the platform and oscpu information. I could guess the values based on the UA string but I want to make sure they are correct

Comment: Thank you  Juan Francisco Cantero Hurtado. That is very helpful. It should be similar for the others BSDs. I will accept that if you want to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

More info from oscpu only adds that FreeBSD amd64 is not supported by this page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Firefox 26 on OpenBSD 5.5 amd64

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Application Basics

```
    Name
    Firefox

    Version
    23.0

    User Agent
    Mozilla/5.0 (X11; FreeBSD i386; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0

    Build Configuration

      about:buildconfig
```

Extensions

```
    Name

    Version

    Enabled

    ID

    Adblock Plus
    2.4
    true
    {d10d0bf8-f5b5-c8b4-a8b2-2b9879e08c5d}

    Fasterfox Lite
    3.9.9Lite
    true
    FasterFox_Lite@BigRedBrent

    NetVideoHunter
    1.15
    true
    netvideohunter@netvideohunter.com

    Vlc context menu
    0.8
    false
    vlcplaylist@helgatauscher.de
```

Important Modified Preferences

```
  Name

  Value

    accessibility.browsewithcaret
    true

    accessibility.typeaheadfind.flashBar
    0

    browser.cache.disk.capacity
    76800

    browser.cache.disk.smart_size_cached_value
    358400

    browser.cache.disk.smart_size.first_run
    false

    browser.cache.disk.smart_size.use_old_max
    false

    browser.places.smartBookmarksVersion
    4

    browser.sessionstore.interval
    300000

    browser.sessionstore.upgradeBackup.latestBuildID
    20131207232409

    browser.startup.homepage_override.buildID
    20130812111814

    browser.startup.homepage_override.mstone
    23.0

    dom.mozApps.used
    true

    dom.w3c_touch_events.expose
    false

    extensions.lastAppVersion
    23.0

    gfx.blacklist.direct2d
    4

    gfx.blacklist.layers.direct3d10
    4

    gfx.blacklist.layers.direct3d10-1
    4

    gfx.blacklist.layers.direct3d9
    4

    gfx.blacklist.layers.opengl
    4

    gfx.blacklist.stagefright
    4

    gfx.blacklist.webgl.angle
    4

    gfx.blacklist.webgl.msaa
    4

    gfx.blacklist.webgl.opengl
    4

    network.cookie.prefsMigrated
    true

    network.dns.disableIPv6
    true

    network.dnsCacheEntries
    512

    network.dnsCacheExpiration
    3600

    network.http.max-connections
    40

    network.http.max-connections-per-server
    16

    network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-proxy
    12

    network.http.pipelining
    true

    network.http.pipelining.maxrequests
    6

    network.http.pipelining.ssl
    true

    network.http.proxy.pipelining
    true

    places.database.lastMaintenance
    1386629750

    places.history.expiration.transient_current_max_pages
    52908

    plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types
    application/pdf

    plugin.importedState
    true

    plugin.state.flash
    1

    print.print_bgcolor
    false

    print.print_bgimages
    false

    print.print_colorspace
    default

    print.print_downloadfonts
    false

    print.print_evenpages
    true

    print.print_in_color
    true

    print.print_margin_bottom
    0.500000012107193

    print.print_margin_left
    0.500000012107193

    print.print_margin_right
    0.500000012107193

    print.print_margin_top
    0.500000012107193

    print.print_oddpages
    true

    print.print_orientation
    1

    print.print_page_delay
    50

    print.print_paper_data
    0

    print.print_paper_height
    297.00

    print.print_paper_name
    iso_a4

    print.print_paper_size_type
    1

    print.print_paper_size_unit
    1

    print.print_paper_width
    210.00

    print.print_plex_name
    default

    print.print_resolution_name
    default

    print.print_scaling
    1.00

    print.print_shrink_to_fit
    true

    print.print_to_file
    false

    print.print_unwriteable_margin_bottom
    56

    print.print_unwriteable_margin_left
    25

    print.print_unwriteable_margin_right
    25

    print.print_unwriteable_margin_top
    25

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.can_change_colorspace
    false

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.can_change_downloadfonts
    false

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.can_change_jobtitle
    false

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.can_change_num_copies
    true

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.can_change_orientation
    true

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.can_change_paper_size
    true

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.can_change_plex
    false

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.can_change_printincolor
    true

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.can_change_resolution
    false

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.can_change_spoolercommand
    true

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.colorspace.0.name
    default

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.colorspace.count
    1

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.has_special_printerfeatures
    true

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.orientation.0.name
    portrait

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.orientation.1.name
    landscape

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.orientation.count
    2

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.paper.0.height_mm
    210

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.paper.0.is_inch
    false

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.paper.0.name
    A5

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.paper.0.width_mm
    148

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.paper.1.height_mm
    297

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.paper.1.is_inch
    false

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.paper.1.name
    A4

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.paper.1.width_mm
    210

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.paper.2.height_mm
    420

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.paper.2.is_inch
    false

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.paper.2.name
    A3

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.paper.2.width_mm
    297

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.paper.3.height_mm
    279

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.paper.3.is_inch
    true

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.paper.3.name
    Letter

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.paper.3.width_mm
    215

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.paper.4.height_mm
    355

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.paper.4.is_inch
    true

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.paper.4.name
    Legal

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.paper.4.width_mm
    215

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.paper.5.height_mm
    431

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.paper.5.is_inch
    true

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.paper.5.name
    Tabloid

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.paper.5.width_mm
    279

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.paper.6.height_mm
    254

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.paper.6.is_inch
    true

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.paper.6.name
    Executive

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.paper.6.width_mm
    190

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.paper.count
    7

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.plex.0.name
    default

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.plex.count
    1

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.resolution.0.name
    default

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.resolution.count
    1

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.supports_colorspace_change
    false

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.supports_downloadfonts_change
    false

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.supports_jobtitle_change
    false

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.supports_orientation_change
    true

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.supports_paper_size_change
    true

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.supports_plex_change
    false

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.supports_printincolor_change
    true

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.supports_resolution_change
    false

    print.tmp.printerfeatures.PostScript/default.supports_spoolercommand_change
    true

    privacy.cpd.offlineApps
    true

    privacy.cpd.sessions
    false

    privacy.cpd.siteSettings
    true

    privacy.sanitize.migrateFx3Prefs
    true

    privacy.sanitize.timeSpan
    0

    storage.vacuum.last.index
    1

    storage.vacuum.last.places.sqlite
    1383844649
```

Graphics

```
    Adapter Description
    Tungsten Graphics, Inc -- Mesa DRI Intel(R) 945GM 20090712 2009Q2 RC3 x86/MMX/SSE2

    Device ID
    Mesa DRI Intel(R) 945GM 20090712 2009Q2 RC3 x86/MMX/SSE2

    Driver Version
    1.4 Mesa 7.6.1

    GPU Accelerated Windows
    0/1 Basic Blocked for your graphics card because of unresolved driver issues.

    Vendor ID
    Tungsten Graphics, Inc

    WebGL Renderer
    Blocked for your graphics card because of unresolved driver issues.

    AzureCanvasBackend
    cairo

    AzureContentBackend
    none

    AzureFallbackCanvasBackend
    none
```

JavaScript

```
    Incremental GC
    true
```

Accessibility

```
    Activated
    false

    Prevent Accessibility
    0
```

Library Versions

```
    Expected minimum version

    Version in use

    NSPR
    4.10
    4.10.1

    NSS
    3.15.1 Basic ECC
    3.15.2 Basic ECC

    NSSSMIME
    3.15.1 Basic ECC
    3.15.2 Basic ECC

    NSSSSL
    3.15.1 Basic ECC
    3.15.2 Basic ECC

    NSSUTIL
    3.15.1
    3.15.2
```

Comment: downvoted because this is a dump of Firefox's `about:support`, which is neither what OP asked for nor useful to OP. as a side note, your Firefox is out-of-date and vulnerable to security threats.